# Kendo UI for jQuery Excel Export format table

Tags: asp.net, excel, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

I use Excel Export of the grid and it works well. like the [excel-export](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export) documentation.

But the excel isn't a table format. I want to export it as a table format automatically and don't want to select `Format as Table` of Excel myself.

[image: Excel Image]

Does Kendo have a way to achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched and read the documentation of Excel Export Kendo, It seems that there isn't any answer to my question right now!